# Trying to open the default browser using xamarin android with c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

so in c# I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https:/.....) and that works great.  So far, everything I've ported over to Xamarin Android has worked, except this.  When this executed in the Android app, nothing...zip...nada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from the Xamarin [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/open_a_webpage_in_the_browser_application/):

```
   var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.xamarin.com");
   var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
   StartActivity (intent);
```

Comment: What is StartActivity method?

Answer (score 0):

You can open `Chrome browser` with url from your app

```
string urlString = "http://google.com";
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(urlString));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.SetPackage("com.android.chrome");
try
{
    context.StartActivity(intent1);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
{
    //Chrome browser not installed
    intent.SetPackage(null);
    context.StartActivity(intent1);
}
```